# Open regular Record Create page from Button on Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce

I have the following button on a vf page.

```
<apex:commandButton value="New Partner Entry" action="{!URLFOR($Action.Partner_c.New)}" />
```

This button, when pressed opens the page in the small VF page on the record layout.

Instead I want a new window to open as if I clicked the "New Partner" button on the standard salesforce page layout related list.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `apex:commandlink` with the `target` parameter, but you'll have to use CSS on the link to make it look like a button.